# Is there a function in jquery that returns a promise if at least one of Deferreds is resolved?

Tags: jquery

I searched the jquery documentation but i can't find a function that has the same goal as jquery.when() but needs at least one deferred to be resolved( not all like jquery.when() ) to be resolved?

Comment: are You looking for function .then()? Please reffer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Do you expect [a method like race()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) as mentioned by m90? How should it handle rejects?  Should it handle both resolve and reject equally with "first wins"? `"The race function returns a Promise that is settled the same way as the first passed promise to settle. It resolves or rejects, whichever happens first."` (from the above docs)

Comment: No. jquery.when() has "AND" between deferrends(if d1&&d2&&d3 then resolve). I need an "OR" (if d1||d2||d3 then resolve).

Comment: Use a third deferred object that is resolved by either of the promises.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's `.race` in jQuery's promise implementation, but you could use another lightweight promise implementation (i.e. `promise.js`) to do so:

```
var one = Promise.resolve($.ajax(/*whatevs*/));
var two = Promise.resolve($.ajax(/*sth else*/));
Promise.race([one,two]).then(function(winner){
// do whatever
});
```

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) and [promise.js](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Alternatively you could also use [`Deferred.progress`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.progress/) together with `.notfiy` in jQuery (although that feels pretty awkward):

```
var one = $.Deferred(function(dfd){
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.notify('foo');
        dfd.resolve('foo');
    }, 200);
});

var two = $.Deferred(function(dfd){
    setTimeout(function(){
        dfd.notify('bar');
        dfd.resolve('bar');
    }, 100);
});


$.when(one, two).progress(function(oneNotification, twoNotification){
    console.log(oneNotification, twoNotification);
}).then(function(oneResult, twoResult){
    console.log(oneResult, twoResult);
});
```